# How to split all the vertically merged cells in Microsoft Word table using word vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, word-table

I have a word table which contains numerous vertical merges.

I need to split all the cells which are merged, into individual cells with the previous value in merged cells.

Comment: Catch here is, i need to know how to split cells to maximum number possible, which is not possible by recording as even while doing manually, we need to enter the number or rows/columns to split the cell manually. But here the code will take care of all that by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched through a lot of reference, but couldn't find any other shorter way to split all vertical merging in Table cell in Word.

This function will take the first table in word, and will remove all the vertical merges for all cells for the table in MS Word.

```
Function SplitVerticalMerge()
    'Created by Chandraprakash [Yoh]
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, cols As Long, m As Long
    Dim sData() As Variant
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oCell As Cell
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim sText As String
    Dim sRow As String
    Dim iRow As Long

    'Rows of Merged and NonMerged cells in Table
    Dim oColl1 As New Collection

    'Row with number of merged cells in Table (Vertical Split Number)
    Dim oColl2 As New Collection

    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    With oTable

        'Load all the Table cell index
        ReDim sData(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To .Columns.Count)
        Set oCell = .Cell(1, 1)
        Do While Not oCell Is Nothing
            sData(oCell.RowIndex, oCell.ColumnIndex) = oCell.RowIndex & "," & oCell.ColumnIndex
            Set oCell = oCell.Next
        Loop

        '1. Mark the merged cell as "X"
        '2. Mark the non merged cell as "A"
        '3. Load the result for each row to Collection1
        For i = 1 To UBound(sData)
            sRow = ""
            For j = 1 To UBound(sData, 2)
                sRow = sRow & IIf(IsEmpty(sData(i, j)), "X", "A") ' & "|"
            Next j
            oColl1.Add sRow
        Next i

        For cols = 1 To oTable.Columns.Count
            'Load one by one Row with number of merged cells in Table (Vertical Split Number)
            Set oColl2 = Nothing
            j = 1
            For i = oColl1.Count To 1 Step -1
                '"X" - Merged
                If Mid(oColl1(i), cols, 1) = "X" Then
                    j = j + 1
                    k = j
                '"A" - NotMerged
                Else
                    k = j
                    j = 1
                End If
                If j = 1 Then oColl2.Add k
            Next i

            iRow = oTable.Columns(cols).Cells.Count
            k = iRow
            For j = 1 To oColl2.Count
                For i = oColl2.Count To 1 Step -iRow
                    'cols - Column Number
                    'k - cell row number in column (cols)
                    'j - Split number for the cell (k)

                    'Split the cell by above attributes defined
                    oTable.Columns(cols).Cells(k).Split oColl2(j), 1

                    '1. Enter if merged cell is split (j>1)
                    '2. Will fill the values for split empty cell with previous merged cell value
                    If oColl2(j) > 1 Then
                        For m = 1 To oColl2(j) - 1
                            oTable.Columns(cols).Cells(k + m).Range.Text = oTable.Columns(cols).Cells(k).Range.Text
                        Next m
                    End If

                    k = k - 1
                Next i
            Next j
        Next cols

        'To avoid application freezing
        DoEvents
    End With

lbl_Exit:
    Set oColl1 = Nothing
    Set oColl2 = Nothing

    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set oCell = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
```

**Reference:** Base code by Graham Mayor - MS MVP (Word)
**URL:** http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?59760-Unmerging-Vertically-merged-cells